# Rails: How to use "joins" in sql query for a has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a User model and a Profile model. Each User has_one profile. The profile has a city attribute. Now, I want the index action of the Users controller to pull all users with the same city as the current_user. So I have this code in the controller:

```
def index @users = User.same_city_as(current_user).paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10 end
```

I also have this is in the User model:

```
scope :same_city_as, lambda { |user| joins(:profile).where(:profile => {:city => user.profile.city} ) }
```

This does not work. I am getting this error " "PGError: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "profile" ".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to make `:profile` in the where clause plural.

```
 joins(:profile).where(:profiles => {:city => user.profile.city})
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use:
...where(user.profile => {city: user.profile.city})